# Grails making image align to center in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

The image default size is :width="65px" height="67px.I want to make it centrally aligned.
If the uploaded image size doesnot match lets say width:100px and height is 20px then i want to make this image align center.

```
 <div class="photo">
        <g:link controller="hcpHubUser" action="edit">
            <g:if test="${userInstance?.serverPictureName}"><r:img
                    uri="/pictures/${userInstance?.serverPictureName}" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: 'default.png')}';" alt="Profile Picture" width="65px"
                    height="67px"/></g:if>
            <g:else><img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'default.png')}" alt="Profile Picture"></g:else>
        </g:link>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS class will center an image on the page regardless of it's size

```
.middle {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Well, strictly speaking, it will center it within it's parent element, but visually it's probably what you want.

Comment: how do i use this? i want code that can be used in my gsp i,e i can add some code to my above code to make it functioning

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code and it worked..

```
<div class="photo">
    <g:link controller="hcpHubUser" action="edit">
        <g:if test="${userInstance?.serverPictureName}"><r:img
                uri="/pictures/${userInstance?.serverPictureName}" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: 'default.png')}';" alt="Profile Picture" width="65px"
                height="67px" style="vertical-align: middle;"/></g:if>
        <g:else><img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'default.png')}" alt="Profile Picture"></g:else>
    </g:link>
</div>
```